# IEEE float hex 424ce027 to float?

Tags: c++, c, hex, ieee-754

If I have a IEEE float hex 424ce027, how do I convert it to decimal?

`unsigned char ptr[] = {0x42,0x4c,0xe0,0x27};`

how do ?

`float tmp = 51.218899;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr);
```

Although on my x86 machine here I had to also reverse the byte order of the character to get the value you wanted.

```
std::reverse(ptr, ptr + 4);
float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr);
```

You might want to use sizeof(float) instead of 4 or some other way to get the size. You might want to reverse a copy of the bytes, not the original. It's somewhat ugly however you do it.

**edit**: As pointed out in the comments, this code is unsafe as it creates two pointers aliasing the same memory but of different types. It may well work on a specific compiler & program, but isn't guarenteed to by the standard.

Comment: @JohnB: I believe this is UB because of the aliasing rules. You cannot some random buffer as `float`.

Comment: I thought there was an exception for char* which was allowed to point to any type, basically for doing exactly this kind of thing? Is my understanding of that rule not correct? (I know it's unsigned char* here which may affect my statement, not sure).

Comment: @JohnB: The rule is only one way, you can view any object as a bunch of characters but not the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. (And slightly annoying :)) Is it "safe" to use memcpy like this :     memcpy(&f, ptr, 4);
With a test it works, and doesn't actually generate any additional code on the compiler I tested it on so is just as efficient. But does is that acceptable with the standard?

Comment: The strict aliasing rules are 6.5/6-7. `memcpy` is OK, because after using it the "effective type" of the target object is `float` (its declared type), and you access it as `float`, no problem. This reinterpret_cast I think is technically not OK, because the "effective type" of the object is array of char, but you access it as float.

Comment: As far as I can tell memcpy is the only safe and standard compliant way to make a float from a char[] then? casting pointers isn't safe because of this strict aliasing, and while using a union may work, it's not quite guarnteed by any standard? (I ask because I've got quite a bit of code that uses casts on pointers to extract fields from network packets, and if i'm going to rewrite it to make it compliant I'd like to make it *right*)

Comment: @JohnB: Yes, `std::memcpy()` is about the only conforming way to do this.

Comment: According to the C specification, 'float' isn't guaranteed to be represented as IEEE-754.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to assume endian and break all sorts of aliasing rules, this kind of thing works well:

```
union IntFloat {
  uint32_t i;
  float f;
};
...
union IntFloat val;
val.i = 0x424ce027;
printf("%f\n", val.f);
```

Still assuming 'float' is 32 bit, and your machine is IEEE-754 compliant, and has matching endian to integers, but we can probably stop being pedantic there.

Comment: The use of the union is GCC extension. It is UB to access union member that has not been written to.

Comment: @wilx: in C++ and (I think) C89. In C99, accessing a different member is not forbidden by 6.5.2.3/3, and a footnote points out that it is permitted. But by doing so you're making assumptions about the layout of the union, in addition to the assumptions that any type-pun makes about storage representations. If all the assumptions are correct (and the layout can be checked - in fact I think it might be guaranteed that each member starts at the start of the union, I just haven't found the reference), then behavior is defined.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: C99 is not C++, it has no bearing on the matter at hand. It is UB in C++.

Comment: @wilx: question is tagged C just as much as it is tagged C++.

Comment: I honestly didn't know it was undefined in C++. This seems a somewhat lazy way to define the spec. At least implementation-defined would infer the intent. Undefined just means a compiler can (and these days will) do whatever it likes. Shame. In any case, there are a lot of other assumptions here, such as IEEE754 on the host. Otherwise, the only 100% portable way to do this is to write an IEEE754 floating point load function.

Answer (score 3):

For converting an integer value I'd do very similar to John Ripley's answer, but a slightly different mechanism. The same caveats apply - float and int must be the same size and endianness, and float must be IEEE if the initial hex value is to be treated as IEEE:

```
float tmp;
unsigned int src = 0x424ce027;
std::memcpy(&tmp, &src, sizeof tmp);
```

You ask how to convert to float, then how to convert to decimal. *Floats are not decimal*. To convert a float to a decimal string, you need something like `printf("%g", tmp);`

If you begin with an array of unsigned char rather than an int, then any direct-copying from the array needs the array to have been populated with the same endianness as on your platform. Your array is big-endian, but Intel is little-endian. So you could `reverse` the array as in JohnB's answer if you know the endianness of your platform is the opposite of the endianness of the array. If you know the array is big-endian, and you don't know what endianness your platform is, you can do this (assuming 8 bits per char in the char array):

```
unsigned int src = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof src; ++i) {
    src = (src << 8) + ptr[i];
}
```

Then continue as before.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: This is not guaranteed to work in Standard C (floating point numbers technically do not have to be IEEE754 binary32/64; they *could* be a decimal implementation).  However, since C99, the standard has declared that IEEE754-style ("IEC 60559") floating point representation is normative and defines it in Annex F.  (And in practice, most hardware you'll encounter uses IEEE754 already.)

This should compile and be correct (with some assertions to be somewhat confident you're dealing with IEEE754 *binary32* floats) on such hardware:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// C99 specifies a "__STDC_IEC_559__" which, if defined, means you
// can be really confident your implementation uses IEEE754 floats.
// Unfortunately, neither GCC nor Clang seems to actually define it.

// Instead, GCC defines a "__GCC_IEC_559", indicating support, and
// glibc on Linux provides a special magic stdc-predef.h header that
// GCC knows about and incorporates into compilation units without
// explicit inclusion.[1]

// So, long story short, if you're on Linux and use glibc and GCC,
// great; just check for __STDC_IEC_559__.  Otherwise:

_Static_asssert(FLT_RADIX == 2, "IEEE754 floats have radix 2");
_Static_asssert(FLT_MANT_DIG == 24 && FLT_MIN_EXP == -125 &&
    FLT_MAX_EXP == 128 && FLT_HAS_SUBNORM == 1,
    "IEEE754 float characteristics");
_Static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "size");

float f;
uint32_t x = 0x424ce027UL;

memcpy(&f, &x, sizeof(f));
printf("%f\n", f));
```

Which gives the output:

> 51.218899

Ref: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2017-January/053186.html

Comment: keep in mind that type punning via pointer casts violates the C aliasing rules (see C99 6.5 §6-7 on effective types), ie the code is non-standard...

Comment: As with the other answers and `int`, this needs `long` to be the same size as `float`. Personally I'm more likely to encounter platforms where `long` is too big (64-bit linux) than where `int` is too small (most 16-bit CPUs), but YMMV. I say "needs", actually it works on little-endian 64-bit linux, but in a way that I'd describe as "by the skin of its teeth" ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I bet it doesn't work on PPC64. With that being said, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The only portable way is to analyze the bit patterns and form the float manually inhering to all rules of ieee-754 floating points:

```
#define BIAS 150
unsigned char ptr[4] = {0x42,0x4c,0xe0,0x27};
// take care of endianness, which may vary between native float and native int
uint32_t tmp = (ptr[0] << 24) | (ptr[1] << 16) | (ptr[2] << 8) | ptr[3];
uint32_t sign = tmp >> 31;
uint32_t exp = (tmp >> 23) & 0xff;
uint32_t mantissa = tmp & ((1 << 23) - 1);
float result;
if (exp > 0)
   mantissa |= (1 << 23);                        // Handle denormals && Inf

// all integers < 16777216 can be represented exactly as a float
// multiply that by a power of two

result = ldexpf((float)mantissa, exp - BIAS);    // in <math.h>

if (exp == 255 && mantissa != 0)  // Produce NaN from Inf-Inf
   result = (result - result);

if (sign) result = -result;       // Flip sign (also handles -0.0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

unsigned char ptr[] = {0x42,0x4c,0xe0,0x27};

float fTemp;

```
uint8_t *temp2 = (uint8_t *) &fTemp;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
    temp2[i] = ptr[3-i];

std::cout<<"Data1: "<<fTemp;
```