# Convert HEX to IEEE 754 float

Tags: bash, ieee-754, modbus

I am writing a bash script to interpret Modbus RTU messages in the Enron history format. The message is binary. I need to convert some of the bytes to 32bit floats. I want to use POSIX available programs or at least very commonly available ones. Bash, AWK, sed, od, etc.

Given 00b74e47 I have tried to use od but I am expecting 52919.000000. od is not giving me the result I am expecting.

```
echo -ne "\x00\xb7\x4e\x47" | od -tfD
0000000          5.91070985e-315
0000004
```

Comment: In C: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165041/3776858

Comment: What is the byte ordering?  474eb700 --> 52919 (FLOAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

od -tfD converts to a double-precision floating-point number. od -tfF will convert to a single-precision floating-point number and will give the expected result.

```
echo -ne "\x00\xb7\x4e\x47" | od -tfF
0000000           52919
0000004
```

Hexdump can also be used. -e tells hexdump to output using a format string. 1/4 tells hexdump to use 4 bytes for the conversion. The %f is to output to a float.

```
echo -ne "\x00\xb7\x4e\x47" | hexdump -e '1/4 "%f" "\n"'
52919.000000
```

Answer (score 4):

If `python3` is your option, please try the following:

```
echo "436a508c" | python3 -c 'import struct; print(struct.unpack("!f", bytes.fromhex(input()))[0])'
```

Yields:

```
234.31463623046875
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Debugger:

```
gdb --batch -ex "print/f (float *) 0x436A508C"
```

Output:

```
$1 = 234.314636
```

---

Source: [Using the linux command line in bash as a programmer's calculator](http://bruxy.regnet.cz/web/linux/EN/bash-as-programmers-calculator/)

Comment: With xargs: `echo "0x436A508C" | xargs -I {} gdb --batch -ex "print/f (float *) {}"`

Comment: The cast to `float*` is superfluous, misleading, and platform-dependent. What it really accomplishes is (roughly speaking) ensuring the integer value is converted to and/or interpreted as a 32-bit memory address (but this only works on 32-bit addressed architectures), and it could easily have been (int*) or simply (int). Furthermore, this would not work at all on architectures with other pointer address widths and implementations.

Comment: The best way to do this is to (1) first determine the integer type with the correct width for the architecture (e.g. unsigned `int`/`long int`/`long long int`; note that fixed-width integer types are not permissible due to not being primitive); (2) then either (a) ensure your (C/C++) integer literal has the correct type to begin with (e.g. `0x436A508C`, `0x436A508Cll`) or (b) perform a type cast to the chosen integer type. The "/f" format flag will then reinterpret the resulting bit pattern as floating point of the same width (usu. IEEE 754 but again this is specific to your architecture).

Comment: Which means you should instead use `print/f 0x436A508C` (for single-precision float) and `print/f 0x436A508Cll` (for double, or `print/f (unsigned long long int) 0x436A508C`), on most architectures where int is 32-bit (i.e. same as single-precision float).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$ crackNum --sp 436A508C
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 10000110 11010100101000010001100
             Hex: 436A 508C
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 7 (Stored: 134, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1.d4a118p7
           Value: +234.31464 (NORMAL)
```

You can write a wrapper around `crackNum` to get rid of the `0x` or post-process the output.

`crackNum` is a Haskell program, you can download it from hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/crackNum